# How to implement multiple if else conditions using SpecFlow C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I am new to Specflow.While writing Feature File,I give 3 Boolean Statements in Given Condition.And in Then Part, I need to check the Result based on given conditions.

It is a basic AND Gate Sample:

```
 Input:  YES   YES    YES
 Output: YES           
 Input:  YES   YES    NO 
 Output: NO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use Scenario Outlines.

Here is an example for it:

```
Scenario Outline: AND Gate   
Given I have the following input on my AND GATE  
 | Input 1  | Input 2  | Input 3  |  
 | <input1> | <input2> | <input3> |

Then I have '<output>' at the output

Examples: | input1 | input2 | input3 | output |
          | Yes    | Yes    | Yes    | Yes    | 
          | Yes    | Yes    | No     | No     |
```

The stuff in the <> brakets are parameters.
See the Gherkin reference for it here: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#scenario-outline